# Filtering a Sencha Touch NestedList TreeStore

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to code an App using Sencha Touch.
For a list of items i've created a NestedList, which displays nodes from a TreeStore, which gets its nodes directly as a list of objects.
Depending on the login-state of the user i want to filter some of those nodes out of the list.

My Setup is as follows:

```
//This is the filter function
var lpFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
  filterFn: function(item) {
    return item.get('type') == 'text';
  }
});

//Create the TreeStore
var myTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  fields: [
    'title','content', 'type', 'xtype', {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
  ],
  root: {
    leaf: false
  },
  filters: [
    lpFilter
  ]
});

//Add the data
myTreeStore.setData(media);

//Nestedlist
var myList = new Ext.NestedList({
  title: 'Mediathek',
  iconCls: 'star',
  displayField: 'title',
  [...]
  store: myTreeStore
});
```

When i run the app, the data gets filtered, store has only 2 items (instead of 5), but my Nestedlist still displays all of them.

Is the Nestedlist simply ignoring my filtering and uses the "all" property of the Store?
Or am I using the filter in a wrong way?

Comment: `lpFilter` is not used in your code

Comment: @kio21 thanks, corrected that. The result is the same though.

Comment: Nope. I ended up filtering manually before passing the data on to the Sencha class...